# MongoError : Can't project geometry into spherical CRS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I am trying to store the location of an entity in Mongo. I seem to be having issues only w.r.t to a few locations that are entered. The error that I get is

MongoError: Can't extract geo keys:can't project geometry into spherical CRS: [ 26.1633829, 91.78194759999997 ]. Is there something wrong with the index. I am working on mongodb version 3.4

My schema is as follows

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var modelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

email: {type: String, lowercase: true},
username: {type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, index: true},
branchName: String,
address: {
    address1: String,
    address2: String,
    locality: String,
    pinCode: Number,
    sublocality_level_2: String,
    sublocality_level_1: String,
    localityName: String,
    administrative_area_level_2: String,
    administrative_area_level_1: String,
    country: String,
    postal_code: String,
    geo: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2dsphere'
    }
},
branchPAN: String,
branchType: String,        
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('SampleModel', modelSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think your problem comes from the type of the point. If you check the documentation, it said that you should use GeoJSON for 2dsphere.

> The 2dsphere index supports data stored as GeoJSON objects and as
>   legacy coordinate pairs (See also 2dsphere Indexed Field
>   Restrictions). For legacy coordinate pairs, the index converts the
>   data to GeoJSON Point. For details on the supported GeoJSON objects,
>   see GeoJSON Objects.

Instead of a single array of numbers, you should use the following format:

```
{ type: "<GeoJSON type>" , coordinates: <coordinates> }
```

There is a mongoose plugin for this: [mongoose-geojson-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-geojson-schema)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 8):

After reading a bit more here.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#point

There is a note in that link

**IMPORTANT
Always list coordinates in longitude, latitude order.**

I was passing values in the other way around.